# How to redirect to login page in php?

Tags: php

I had a problem facing that when we are in a page after login to the site then after some time we do loggedout from the page 
Now my question is that after logged out if anyone copies the url and opened in the another browser it should be direct them to the login page
The code should contain the function 
and that function should call in another php file like call function()

Answer (score 3):

write below code on **logout.php**

```
session_start(); 
//or  @session_start() if session already started before this line
session_destroy();
session_unset();
session_write_close();
session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION = array();
header("Location:index.php");
exit();
```

more examples can be seen on **[session manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)**

Comment: Im trying if user logins the page will be redirect to another page.... then i have a my account page in our site....if user loggedout it goes to login page.....if user knows url if user enters myaccount url the page is opening...that should not be done..... i need using if(isset($_cookie["user"])); this code should be done in another php page... that page should be use in what ever page i have to use.....@Wayne Whitty